# Custom React Drawer Navigation

Tags: react-native

i'm currently trying to implement custom component to show the icon i've.
i got no error when rendering it , but 2 of list of screen didn't shows up. am i need to do something with styling or there's a problem with my code

if anyone could inspect my code that would be awesome

[this is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMUac.png)

here are my code

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    SafeAreaView,
    ScrollView,
    Dimensions,
    Image,
    Text
 } from 'react-native';
import {
     createDrawerNavigator,
     DrawerItems
    } from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from './screen/HomeScreen';
import SettingsScreen from './screen/SettingsScreen';


export default class App extends React.Component {
    render () { 
        return (
            <AppDrawerNavigator />
        );
    }
}

const CustomDrawerComponent = ( props ) => (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
        <ScrollView>
             <View style={{height:150,backgroundColor:'white',alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                 <Image 
                 source={require('./img/cs.png')} 
                 style={{height:120, width:120, borderRadius: 20}}
                 />
             </View>
        </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
)

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator ({
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Settings: SettingsScreen
},{  
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent

})

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 0,
        color: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});
```

Homescreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';

class HomeScreen extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Home</Text> 
        </View>
        );
    }
}

export default HomeScreen ;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        color: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});
```

Comment: you mean Drawer Labels didnt show up ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official doc, your Drawer Navigator has to be defined like:

```
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsScreen,
  }
});
```

You're not assigning an object with a prop `screen` to each custom screen.
For more details take a look at [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html).

Answer (score 0):

as I understand, you need to add DrawerItems to your drawer.

```js
  

 import { DrawerItems, SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation';
   const CustomDrawerComponent = ( props ) => (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
        <ScrollView>
             <View style={{height:150,backgroundColor:'white',alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                 <Image 
                 source={require('./img/cs.png')} 
                 style={{height:120, width:120, borderRadius: 20}}
                 />
            
             </View>
           <DrawerItems {...props} />
        </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
)
```